# Cycle through a variable range of cells and fill empty cells with a certain character

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am learning VBA as I go along and have managed to compile a lot of code from a range of sources but am finding it hard to solve my current problem. I have read a lot of solutions regarding working with ranges but I have been unable to adapt any of the ones that I have seen to resolve my issue.

I would like a macro which, when a Command Button is pressed, will identify the last used row in a range of cells (which will increase in row count over time) then check each row for any empty cells within the range and filling these with the letter 'N' if there is data in the same row in Column A.

I currently have the following code:

```
Private Sub CBtnFillAll_Click()
'
' EmptyCharacteristic Macro
' Fills empty cells in the characteristics columns with 'N'
'

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rRng = ActiveSheet.Range("$H$3:$S" & Lastrow)

For Each rCell In rRng.Rows
    If rCell.Value = "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(rRng.Row, 1).Value <> "" Then
    rCell.Value = "N"
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

I am checking Column A as there is additional data starting in Column B in rows which I do not want to include in the range. The range to check will always be between Columns H and S.

I am currently getting a 'Type Mismatch' error in the following line:

```
If rCell.Value = "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(rRng.Row, 1).Value <> "" Then
```

Please can someone help me with the syntax in this final part?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to get the value of a range that holds an entire column with the `If rCell.Value = ""` snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this may do what you are looking for

```
Sub CBtnFillAll_Click()
' EmptyCharacteristic Macro
' Fills empty cells in the characteristics columns with 'N'
'
    Dim rCell   As Range, _
        rRng    As Range

    For Each rRng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:A").Cells
        If IsEmpty(rRng) Then GoTo NextRow
        For Each rCell In rRng.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 12)
            If IsEmpty(rCell) Then rCell.Value = "N"
        Next rCell
NextRow:
    Next rRng

End Sub
```

If you are looking to omit the first two lines of your sheet, then you can change

```
For Each rRng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:A").Cells
```

to

```
For Each rRng In ActiveSheet.[A3].Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count-2)
```

Comment: Thanks Taylor - I have learned a little more from you today. I have gone with this answer as it was the first one to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is completely correct, but there is one thing that creates the problem:

Change your `For Each` line to this: `For Each rCell in rRng`.

There are a few things I would have done differently, so here is my complete code:

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim Currentrow As Long

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rRng = ActiveSheet.Range("H3:S" & Lastrow)

For Each rCell In rRng
    Currentrow = rCell.Row
    Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Currentrow)
    If Not IsEmpty(aCell.Value) And IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
    rCell.Value = "N"
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you DirtyDeffy - I've learned a little more today! I've upvoted your answer but it won't show up due to my low rep!

Comment: Glad to help - no worries about the rep ;)